# Can the data type returned by a field annotated with @Relation be a DatabaseView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a class, Category that's a POJO, but it throws an error,

```
error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: itemCategoryId)
```

The Category class is

```
data class Category(
    @Embedded
    val category: CategoryTable,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "category_id",
        entityColumn = "itemCategoryId"
    )
    val inventoryItems: List<InventoryItem>
) : InventoryAccess {

    override val id: Long
        get() = category.categoryId
}
```

The InventoryItem is database view defined as:

```
@DatabaseView(
    """
    SELECT
     i.item_id AS itemId,
     i.name as name,
     i.price as price,
     i.item_code as itemCode,
     i.quantity as quantity,
     i.description as description,
     shelf.units_remaining + sum(w.units_in_si_unit) as unitsRemaining,
     image.uri as uri
    from item_table i
    left join item_image_table image on image.image_item_id = i.item_id and image.is_feature_image = 1
    inner join shelf_table shelf on shelf.shelf_item_id = i.item_id
    left join ware_house_table w on w.ware_house_item_id = i.item_id
    group by item_id
    order by i.name asc
"""
)
@Keep
data class InventoryItem(
    override val itemId: Long,
    override val name: String,
    override val price: Double,
    override val quantity: ImmutableQuantity,
    override val uri: Uri?,
    override val unitsRemaining: Double?,
    val itemCategoryId: Long,
    val itemCode: String?,
    val description: String?,
) : ItemStructure, InventoryAccess {
    override val id: Long get() = itemId
}
```

What is the issue with the inventoryItems field definition.

I was trying to create a one to many relationship between the category and the inventory item which is a database view. However when I use the POJO with @Relation annotation, I get the error as described earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `@Relation` Room generates the underlying extraction (query) of the `@Relation` object for each `@Embedded` object extracted. As such it will, I believe, use the columns as per the output/select used for the database view.

In your case there is no column output that is named `itemCategoryId` the only output columns are:-

- itemId,
- name,
- price,
- itemCode,
- quantity,
- description,
- unitsRemaining, and
- uri

Now if you had, for example:-

```
SELECT
 i.item_id AS itemId,
 i.name as name,
 i.price as price,
 i.item_code as itemCode,
 i.quantity as quantity,
 i.description as description,
 shelf.units_remaining + sum(w.units_in_si_unit) as unitsRemaining,
 image.uri as uri,
 1 AS itemcategoryid /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
```

Then I believe that the column will then exist. **Obviously the value of 1 would very likely not be what is wanted.**

> Can the data type returned by a field annotated with @Relation be a DatabaseView

**Yes**. To all intents and purposes, the View is like a Table. In fact if you look at the class named the same as the `@Database` annotated class and find the **createAlTables** method in generated java then you will see the **CREATE VIEW** sql. e.g. for the demo below:-

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW `TestView` AS SELECT id AS idother, thecolumn AS theColumnother, id AS another, 12 as yetanother FROM thetable");
```

Perhaps consider this demo that uses the following Entities/POJOs/Dao and Database:-

```
@Entity
data class TheTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val theColumn: String
)

@DatabaseView("SELECT id AS idother, thecolumn AS theColumnother, id AS another, 12 as yetanother FROM thetable")
data class TestView(
    val idother: Long,
    val theColumnother: String,
    val another: Long,
    val yetanother: Long
)

data class POJOOneToOneTest(
    @Embedded
    val theTable: TheTable,
    @Relation(
        entity = TestView::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "another"
    )
    val testViews: List<TestView>
)

@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(theTable: TheTable): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM thetable")
    fun getPOJOOneToOneTests(): List<POJOOneToOneTest>
}
@Database(entities = [TheTable::class], views = [TestView::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of the demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Noting that to ensure a relationship that the referenced child value (another) is set to the parent value.

And then with the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db= TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao=db.getAllDAOs()

        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Apple"))
        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Banana"))
        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Cherry"))
        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Damson"))


        for (potot in dao.getPOJOOneToOneTests()) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (tv in potot.testViews) {
                sb.append("\n\t TVIDOther is ${tv.idother} TVAnother is ${tv.another} TVColumnOther is ${tv.theColumnother} TV Yetanother is ${tv.yetanother}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","TheTable ID is ${potot.theTable.id} TheColumn is ${potot.theTable.theColumn} it has ${potot.testViews.size} TestViews. They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:-

```
D/DBINFO: TheTable ID is 1 TheColumn is Apple it has 1 TestViews. They are:-
         TVIDOther is 1 TVAnother is 1 TVColumnOther is Apple TV Yetanother is 12
D/DBINFO: TheTable ID is 2 TheColumn is Banana it has 1 TestViews. They are:-
         TVIDOther is 2 TVAnother is 2 TVColumnOther is Banana TV Yetanother is 12
D/DBINFO: TheTable ID is 3 TheColumn is Cherry it has 1 TestViews. They are:-
         TVIDOther is 3 TVAnother is 3 TVColumnOther is Cherry TV Yetanother is 12
D/DBINFO: TheTable ID is 4 TheColumn is Damson it has 1 TestViews. They are:-
         TVIDOther is 4 TVAnother is 4 TVColumnOther is Damson TV Yetanother is 12
```

So the single related TestView is retrieved from the View (`@DatabaseView` in Room).

Obviously the example has been created just to demonstrate the possibility of using a View within an `@Relation`, it is not intended to reflect your situation.